# How do I provide multiple members to a Redis set using Lua when number of members is unknown until run-time?

Tags: lua, redis, set, arguments

For example, it's possible to add multiple members to some *set* in Redis using the `sadd` command this way:

```
sadd myset 38 484 2 92 1
```

In Lua, I've found I can perform the same operation as follows:

```
redis.call("SADD", "myset", "38", "484", "2", "92", "1")
```

But, what happens when the caller doesn't know how many arguments will provide to `sadd`?

In JavaScript, there's the `Function.apply(...)` function which lets provide arguments in order as an array:

```
 // Source function would look like this: function X(a, b, c) { ... }
 X.apply(this, [38, 484, 2]);
```

How do I achieve the same goal in Lua and Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unpack to create similar functionality to apply:

```
  function apply(f, args) f(unpack(args)) end

  function X(a, b, c) print(a, b, c) end

  apply(X, {38, 484, 2})
```

or simply unpack directly:

```
  X(unpack{38, 484, 2})
```

Comment: I'm going this way... I've also found the thing about `unpack` on the net. Now I need to get my code working

Comment: Oh yeah! I got it finally working and obviously, it was using `unpack`. I had extra work because I'm adding members to a sorted set too and I've needed to create a Lua table on the fly adding the scores to the members to be added...